# multiple rows into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I trying to create a query in SQL SERVER 2008 that will display multiple row into a single row per account.

The table is currently displaying the data like so...(also the number of cds for each account is not the same)

table  query

```
SELECT 
  [ACCOUNTNO]
  ,DT
  ,POSTDT
  ,CD
  ,NO
  ,SEQNO
 FROM [dbo].[DInformation]
```

results

```
ACCOUNTNO   DT          POSTDT      CD      NO  SEQNO
50000878915 06/29/2011  06/29/2011  52074   639 2005
50000878915 07/03/2008  07/03/2008  6650222 749 3008
50000878915 07/03/2008  07/09/2008  6720030 644 3032
50000878915 07/23/2008  07/23/2008  99801   995 2055
50000878915 07/23/2008  07/23/2008  99801   995 2056
50000878915 07/23/2008  07/23/2008  7109045 994 2134
50000878915 07/10/2008  07/10/2008  52017   996 169
50000878915 07/23/2008  07/23/2008  99801   995 2055
50000878915 07/23/2008  07/23/2008  99801   995 2056
50000878915 07/23/2008  07/23/2008  30010   992 2087
50000878915 07/23/2008  07/23/2008  52038   993 2032
65478078915 10/01/2012  01/09/2013  6910002 871 3076
65478078915 11/01/2012  01/09/2013  6910002 888 3055
65478078915 12/01/2012  01/09/2013  6910002 6   3085
65478078915 01/01/2013  02/06/2013  6910002 918 3009
65478078915 02/01/2013  03/05/2013  6910002 668 3018
65478078915 03/01/2013  04/04/2013  6910002 24  3065
```

I would like the results to display like so...

```
50000878915 06/29/2011  06/29/2011  52074   639 2005 07/03/2008 07/03/2008     6650222  749 3008 07/03/2008 07/09/2008  6720030 644 3032 07/23/2008 07/23/2008  99801   995 2055 07/23/2008 07/23/2008  99801   995 2056 07/23/2008 07/23/2008  7109045 994 2134 07/10/2008 07/10/2008  52017   996 169 07/23/2008  07/23/2008  99801   995 2055 07/23/2008 07/23/2008  99801   995 2056 07/23/2008 07/23/2008  30010   992 2087 07/23/2008 07/23/2008  52038   993 2032
65478078915 10/01/2012  01/09/2013  6910002 871 3076 11/01/2012 01/09/2013  6910002 888 3055 12/01/2012 01/09/2013  6910002 6   3085 01/01/2013 02/06/2013  6910002 918 3009 02/01/2013 03/05/2013  6910002 668 301803/01/2013  04/04/2013  6910002 24  3065
```

any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Can you explain in words what you're trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to get the oldest DT for every account?

Comment: What are you doing please explain in Brief

Comment: I want to combine all the multiples rows to one based on the account. so for all 12 rows for 50000878915 i would like to see the results in one row and 65478078915 all 6 row in one rows etc. I'm very Sorry if my post was not clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `XML` functionality if you just want to list them out like your sample shows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       ACCOUNTNO
      ,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONCAT(DT,POSTDT,CD,NO,SEQNO)
              FROM Table1 a 
              WHERE a.ACCOUNTNO = b.ACCOUNTNO
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

FROM Table1 b
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9e202/4/0)

If you want to have them be proper fields then you're looking at some `PIVOT` action.

Edit: Note the `CONCAT()` function was added in 2012, if using prior version cast each field to string and concatenate via `+`.

Comment: I'm receiving the following error...'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. I'm currently using sql server 2008

Comment: See note at bottom, you'll have to `CAST(fieldname AS VARCHAR(25))` each field.